# How to make background video playlist with sound to work

Tags: javascript, html, background, http-status-code-404

Videos will not play as background. How do I go about fixing this?
The Videos are the red screen of death from Playstation 2.
I tried other videos but now it does not work.
The 2 js files are needed.

```
<script src="https://robocop79.github.io/JS/vbacksound.js"></script>
<script src="https://robocop79.github.io/JS/vbackplay404.js"></script>

<style>
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.flexible {
    position:absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.myClass {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 3em;
}

.myClass ul li {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20pt;
    line-height: 30pt;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.content {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.bgv-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: -998;
}

p {
    color: #eee;
}
</style>
```

I expect a background video playlist with sound, but nothing happens.

Comment: Why is there HTML in your css?

Comment: the html loads js files

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more code. What does your HTML file look like?

You can follow this Mozilla article to get you started:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: The video was playing for me. What is the expected outcome?

Comment: A playlist with the code provided above. The video is not a playlist currently